# Populate one dropdown list based on the selection of other dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to populate one dropdown list based on the selection of other dropdown list. This is what I have till now.

This is the function that receive as a parameter the selected value for the first dropdownlist:

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult GetTownsForCounty(string selectedCounty)
    {

        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list.Add(new SelectListItem{Text=selectedCounty+"1", Value=selectedCounty+"1", Selected=false});
        list.Add(new SelectListItem{Text=selectedCounty+"2", Value=selectedCounty+"2", Selected=false});
        list.Add(new SelectListItem{Text=selectedCounty+"3", Value=selectedCounty+"3", Selected=false});

        var dropdowndata = list;

        return Json(dropdowndata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.County, counties)
@Html.DropDownListFor(item => item.Town, new List<SelectListItem>())
```

My javascript:

```
    $.get("/Subscription/GetTownsForCounty", { selectedCounty: county }, function (dropdowndata) {
        console.log(dropdowndata)

        var select = $("#Town");
        select.empty();
        $.each(dropdowndata, function (index, itemData) {
            select.append($('<option/>', {
                value: itemData.Value,
                text: itemData.Text
            }));
        });

    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I remove from route config next line it works:

```
  routes.MapRoute(name: "Subscription", 
    url: "subscription/{id}/{name}",
    defaults: new {
      controller="Subscription",
      action="Index",
      id=UrlParameter.Optional,
      name=UrlParameter.Optional});
```

If not, the response(dropdowndata) is the html of the page. Why?

Comment: What happens at the minute?

Comment: I don't know, what is it doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answering your question about the route:

Your route that you remove has `subscription/{id}/{name}`, which means that when you try to request `/Subscription/GetTownsForCounty`, it's trying to pass `GetTownsForCountry` as the `Id` parameter to the Index action, instead of calling the `GetTownsForCountry` Action. When you remove this, it's probably falling back to the default route of `{controller}/{action}/{id}`, so that your request calls the correct action.

#### An important point:

You're trying to return JSON serialized `SelectListItems` which is not right. You should just return raw data as JSON, and build the select options on the client. It still works using SelectListItem, because it ends up just creating objects with those properties anyway, but you really shouldn't do it that way, because you're effectively creating controls, turned to data, turned to controls, which is not a good pattern.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetTownsForCounty(string selectedCounty)
{

    List<object> list = new List<object>();
    list.Add(new {Text=selectedCounty+"1", Value=selectedCounty+"1"});
    list.Add(new {Text=selectedCounty+"2", Value=selectedCounty+"2"});
    list.Add(new {Text=selectedCounty+"3", Value=selectedCounty+"3"});

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Even though SelectListItems isn't really a control, but just a class I'm personally undecided; yes it's another mapping from one class to another, but on the other hand the code is clearing (unambiguously) returning items for a select list and that could be used generically on the client side for all drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to generate a `SelectList` on the controller since that is a view concern.

Try

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult GetTownsForCounty(string selectedCounty)
{
    var list = new List<object>();
    list.Add(new object { Text = selectedCounty + "1", Value = selectedCounty + "1" });
    list.Add(new object { Text = selectedCounty + "2", Value = selectedCounty + "2" });
    list.Add(new object { Text = selectedCounty + "3", Value = selectedCounty + "3" });
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Same..... The problem is this line from RouteConfig (routes.MapRoute.... see my post). If I remove this line everything works great.